# React hooks: Call props.function in child after a fetch return

Tags: reactjs

**UPDATE**

My problem was on the backend, where my JSON was not being returned to my fetch call. Silly mistake. The below front-end code should work.

---

I have a child component that is receiving a function, `increment()` from its parent. Its job is to increment a number in the parent component by 1. I am passing it down to the child component and want to call it after a fetch return is completed in the child component. However, it is not being called. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the Parent component:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    console.log("increment called");
    setI(i + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Child increment={ increment } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the child component:

```
const Child = (props) => {

  const doSomething = () => {
    fetch("/dosomething")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      props.increment(); // <-- want this to be called here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err : ", err);
    });
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={ doSomething }>Do Something</Button>
  )
};
```

Comment: are you sure it is actually reaching `props.increment()`? do a `console.log(json)` just before it and see if it gets there

Comment: fetch is asynchronous, meaning it should be in useEffect hook.

Comment: @Cornel Ah, you were right, had a problem on my backend that wasn't returning the json. Silly mistake. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Above code works.

Answer (score 1):

> try using this in parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child';

const Parent = () => {
    const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);

    const increment = () => {
      console.log("increment called");
      setI(i + 1);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Child increment={ increment } />
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Parent;
```

> In Child Component do this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = (props) => {


    const doSomething = () => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
        props.increment(); // increment is called here
        console.log(json)// <-- sample JSON Data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err : ", err);
        });

    }

    return (
      <button onClick={ doSomething }>Do Something</button>
    )
  };

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this method on the increment function

```
const increment = () => {
    console.log("increment called");
    setI( prevI => prevI + 1);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an isFetching state to your Child component. Start it with false default. When you click the button, change it to true. Then do your fetch call when isFetching is true. Turn it back to false after your increment function.

```
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if(isFetching) {
    fetch("/dosomething")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      props.increment(); // <-- want this to be called here
      setIsFetching(false)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err : ", err);
    });
}
}, [isFetching]);
```

For your button:

```
<Button onClick={ () => setIsFetching(true) }>Do Something</Button>
```